# My Success Message (Alert Message) doesn't vanish

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

My applications has different sides on which the user can add Hardware. If the user successfully add a item a Success Message is shown which vanish after a few seconds. Unfortunetly on one side it won't vanish. Does somebody know why?

On this side the message does vanish:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Greenify | Travel</title>

    <!-- ############### -->
    <!-- ## CSS Files ## -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap Font Icon CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/main.css}"  href="../static/css/main.css">

    <!-- Cards CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/cards.css}" href="../static/css/cards.css">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- JS-File with Dashboard-Charts -->
    <script th:src="@{js/dimensions_it_travel_expenses.js}" src="../static/js/dimensions_it_travel_expenses.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript to save data for charts in Model-->
    <script>
        oEmissions = [];
        oEmissions.emissions_total = [[${emissions_total}]];

        oEmissions.emissions_flights = [[${emission_value_flights}]];
        oEmissions.emissions_train = [[${emission_value_trains}]];
        oEmissions.emissions_car = [[${emission_value_cars}]];
        oEmissions.emissions_hotel = [[${emission_value_hotels}]];
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100 overflow-hidden">
    <!--Toolbar -->
    <div th:insert="fragments/topbar :: topbar"></div>

    <!-- Add Travel Expenses travel based - Modal -->
    <div th:insert="fragments/ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Add :: ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Add"></div>


    <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="col-auto  mh-100 overflow-hidden flex-shrink-0">

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <navbar th:include="fragments/sidebar :: sidebar(dashboardActive='', dimensionsActive='active', decarbonizeActive='')"></navbar>
        </div>
        <div class='col mh-100 overflow-auto pe-4'>

            <!-- Row 1 (Headline) -->
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Headline Dimensions -->
                <h1 class="display-6 text-center">IT - Travel Expenses</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- Test Yearly Emissions<span th:each="year : ${yearlyEmissions}" th:text="${year.getValue()} + ', '">, </span> -->

            <!-- Success Message -->
            <!-- Error Label -->
            <div th:if="${error}" th:text="${error}" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3 " style="margin-top: 4.5rem; margin-right: 2rem"/>
            <!-- Success Label -->
            <div th:if="${success}" th:text="${success}" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3 " style="margin-top: 4.5rem; margin-right: 2rem"/>

           

            <!-- Accordion with tables -->
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
                <!-- Accordion-Item 1: Travel Expenses -->
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header card shadow" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed p-4" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
                            <h5>Travel Expenses (<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(emissions_total, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></span> CO<sub>2</sub>e)</h5>
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <!-- Button to add Travel Expenses via Modal -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm mb-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Add" style="background-color: var(--own-green-2); float: right;">
                                <i class="bi bi-plus-lg" style="color: white;"></i>
                            </button>

                            <!-- Check if there are entries for trips. If there are no entries, a hint text will be displayed -->
                            <div th:if="__${trips.size()}__ == 0">
                                <p class="fs-6">Currently there are no entries for trips. You can add them via the add button!</p>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Check if there are entries for trips table -->
                            <div th:if="__${trips.size()}__ >= 1">
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <thead class="table-light text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Title</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Startdate</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Enddate</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Amount of Persons</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Overnight Stays</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Travel Destination</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Details</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Actions</th>

                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-center">
                                    <tr th:each="trip : ${trips}">
                                        <td th:text="${trip.travelName}">Business Trip 1</td>
                                        <td th:text="${#temporals.format(trip.startDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}">2000-08-2</td>
                                        <td th:text="${#temporals.format(trip.endDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}">2000-08-22</td>
                                        <td th:text="${trip.participants}">4</td>
                                        <td th:text="${trip.stays} + ' days'">5</td>
                                        <td th:text="${trip.destinationCountry}">Italy</td>
                                        <td><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-up-right" role="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" th:attr="data-bs-target='#ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Details' + ${trip.id }"></i></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <table class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                <tr>
    <!--                                                <td>-->
    <!--                                                    <div>-->
    <!--                                                        <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill text-primary me-3" style="cursor: pointer"-->
    <!--                                                           data-bs-toggle="modal" th:attr="data-bs-target='#ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Update' + ${trip.id }"></i>-->
    <!--                                                    </div>-->
    <!--                                                </td>-->
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div>
                                                            <i class="bi bi-trash-fill text-danger" role="button" type="submit" style="cursor: pointer"
                                                               data-bs-toggle="modal" th:attr="data-bs-target='#ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Delete' + ${trip.id }"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <!-- Delete Travel Expense - Modal-->
                                                <div th:insert="fragments/ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Delete :: ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Delete"></div>
                                                <!-- Update Travel Expense - Modal-->
                                                <div th:insert="fragments/ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Update :: ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Update"></div>

                                            </table>
                                            <!-- Travel Detail Information Expense - Modal-->
                                            <div th:insert="fragments/ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Details :: ITTravelExpenses_Modal_Details"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

            

             

                <!-- Accordion-Item 5: Hotel -->
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header card shadow" id="panelsStayOpen-headingFive">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed p-4" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseFive">
                            <h5>Hotel (<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(emission_value_hotels, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></span> CO<sub>2</sub>e)</h5>
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseFive" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingFive">
                        <div class="accordion-body">

                            <!-- Check if there are entries for hotelovernights. If there are no entries, a hint text will be displayed -->
                            <div th:if="__${hotelovernights.size()}__ == 0">
                                <p class="fs-6">Currently there are no entries for hotel overnight stays.</p>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Check if there are entries for hotelovernights table -->
                            <div th:if="__${hotelovernights.size()}__ >= 1">
                                <!-- Table with Hotel -->
                                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <thead class="table-light text-center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Name of Trip</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Location</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Amount overnight stays</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Amount of Traveller</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody class="text-center">
                                    <tr th:each="hotel : ${hotelovernights}">
                                        <td th:text="${hotel.trip.travelName}">1</td>
                                        <td th:text="${hotel.country}">Land</td>
                                        <td th:text="${hotel.amountOfOvernightStays}">tage</td>
                                        <td th:text="${hotel.trip.participants}">4</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            <br>
            <br>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Javascript Imports -->
<script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js" integrity="sha384-uO3SXW5IuS1ZpFPKugNNWqTZRRglnUJK6UAZ/gxOX80nxEkN9NcGZTftn6RzhGWE" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha384-zNy6FEbO50N+Cg5wap8IKA4M/ZnLJgzc6w2NqACZaK0u0FXfOWRRJOnQtpZun8ha" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

While on this side the Message does not vanish:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico" />

    <title>Greenify | IT Infrastructure</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/main.css}" href="../static/css/main.css"/>

    <!-- Bootstrap Font Icon CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"/>

    <!-- Cards CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/cards.css}" href="../static/css/cards.css">

    <!-- JS-File with Charts -->
    <script th:src="@{js/dimension_it_infrastructure.js}" src="../static/js/dimension_it_infrastructure.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript to save data for charts in Model-->
    <script>
      oEmissions = [];
      oEmissions.emissions_total = [[${emissions_total}]];
      oEmissions.emissions_servers = [[${servers_emissions}]];
      oEmissions.emissions_clouds = [[${cloud_emissions}]];

      // Labels and Values for IT Equipment CO2 Emissions Line Chart
      aTotalEmissionsByYearITInfraLabels = [[${total_emissions_by_year_it_infra_labels}]];
      aTotalEmissionsByYearITInfraValuesNow = [[${total_emissions_by_year_it_infra_valuesNow}]];
      aTotalEmissionsByYearITInfraValuesFC = [[${total_emissions_by_year_it_infra_valuesFC}]];
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100 overflow-hidden">
      <!--Toolbar -->
      <div th:insert="fragments/topbar :: topbar"></div>

      <!-- Add IT-Infrastructure Own Data Center - Modal -->
      <div th:insert="fragments/ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Add :: ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Add"></div>

      <!-- Add IT-Infrastructure Cloud - Modal -->
      <div th:insert="fragments/ITInfrastructure_Cloud_Modal_Add :: ITInfrastructure_Cloud_Modal_Add"></div>

      <!-- Page content -->
      <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="col-auto mh-100 overflow-hidden flex-shrink-0">
          <!-- Sidebar -->
          <navbar th:include="fragments/sidebar :: sidebar(dashboardActive='', dimensionsActive='active', decarbonizeActive='')"></navbar>
        </div>

        <!-- Content Section -->
        <div class="col mh-100 overflow-auto pe-4">

          <!-- Row 1 (Headline) -->
          <div class="row">
            <h1 class="display-6 text-center">IT - Infrastructure</h1>
          </div>

          <!-- Error Label -->

          <div th:if="${error}" th:text="${error}" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3" style="margin-top: 4.5rem; margin-right: 2rem"/>
          <!-- Success Label -->

          <div th:if="${success}" th:text="${success}" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3" style="margin-top: 4.5rem; margin-right: 2rem"/>



        

          <!-- Accordion with tables of Own Data Centers and Cloud -->
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionPanelsStayOpenExample">
            <!-- Accordion-Item 1: Own Data Centers -->
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header card shadow" id="panelsStayOpen-headingOne">
                <button
                  class="accordion-button collapsed p-4"
                  type="button"
                  data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#panelsStayOpen-collapseOne"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-controls="panelsStayOpen-collapseTwo">
                  <h5>Own Data Centers (<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(servers_emissions, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}">0</span>kg CO<sub>2</sub>e)
                  </h5>
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="panelsStayOpen-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="panelsStayOpen-headingTwo">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <!-- Button to add Own Data Centers via Modal -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm mb-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Add" style="background-color: var(--own-green-2); float: right">
                    <i class="bi bi-plus-lg" style="color: white"></i>
                  </button>

                  <!-- Check if there are entries for servers table. If there are no entries, a hint text will be displayed -->
                  <div th:if="__${servers.size()}__ == 0">
                    <p class="fs-6">
                      Currently there are no entries for own data centers. You
                      can add them via the add button!
                    </p>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Check if there are entries for servers table -->
                  <div th:if="__${servers.size()}__ >= 1">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                      <thead class="table-light text-center">
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Title</th>
                          <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                          <th scope="col">Location</th>
                          <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                          <th scope="col">Period of use</th>
                          <th scope="col">State</th>
                          <th scope="col">Power Consumption Active Mode</th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            Daily Usage in Active Mode (in hours)
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">Power Consumption IDLE Mode</th>
                          <th scope="col">
                            Daily Usage in IDLE Mode (in hours)
                          </th>
                          <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="text-center">
                        <tr th:each="server : ${servers}">
                          <!--<td th:text="${tablet.id}">1</td>-->
                          <td th:text="${server.title}">5</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.amount}">5</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.location}">Germany</td>
                          <td th:text="${#temporals.format(server.startDate, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}">Lenovo</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.periodOfUse}">4</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.state}">4</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.activeMode}">60</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.usageActiveMode}">60</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.standbyMode}">60</td>
                          <td th:text="${server.usageStandbyMode}">60</td>
                          <td>
                            <table class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                              <tr>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill text-primary me-3" style="cursor: pointer" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Update"
                                      th:attr="data-bs-target='#ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Update' + ${server.id}"
                                    ></i>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  <div>
                                    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill text-danger" role="button" type="submit" style="cursor: pointer" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                      data-bs-target="#ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Delete" th:attr="data-bs-target='#ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Delete' + ${server.id}"
                                    ></i>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>

                              <!-- Update IT Infrastructure Own Data Centers - Modal -->
                              <div th:insert="fragments/ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Update :: ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Update"></div>

                              <!-- Delete IT Infrastructure Own Data Centers - Modal -->
                              <div th:insert="fragments/ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Delete :: ITInfrastructure_OwnDataCenter_Modal_Delete"></div>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <br/>

           

            <br/>
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Javascript Imports -->
    <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/feather-icons@4.28.0/dist/feather.min.js" integrity="sha384-uO3SXW5IuS1ZpFPKugNNWqTZRRglnUJK6UAZ/gxOX80nxEkN9NcGZTftn6RzhGWE" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha384-zNy6FEbO50N+Cg5wap8IKA4M/ZnLJgzc6w2NqACZaK0u0FXfOWRRJOnQtpZun8ha" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Java Script coding to let the Message vanish is the following:

```
/* globals Chart:false, feather:false */

window.onload = function () {

        // This coding let the Success Message vanish after some time
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // autodismiss alerts
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, 4000);
    });
}
```

I load the Java Script coding in a extra file but it doesn't causes the problem, even if i put the coding in the same file in which the coding for the side is, it still does not vanish....
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Okay, what I think your problem is that first, you show the alert, then remove it, and use two different functions.

Comment: It is not a problem on other sides, I just don't know why it don't remove the message on the "IT Infrastructure" side.